# Using jQuery.ScrollTo to scroll down when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link on top of my page Categories
when this is clicked, the page jumps to the bottom where the target div is located

I am trying to use jQuery.ScrollTo but its not working. I am not sure how to debug.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{


    // Scroll the content inside the #scroll-container div
    $('.categories_link').scrollTo({
       target:'#categories'
    });

});
```

**UPDATE:**
Found this http://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/ so now trying to modify it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should it scroll to the bottom or not? Post your code.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have pasted the JavaScript I am using. I assume its wrong. the link which user clicks has a class .categories_link and the bottom div has an id #categories

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS at all. Just use

```
<a class="categories_link" href="#categories">Click me!</a>
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/ezCFC/

Comment: Yes am doing this now. I need the scrolling to be smooth. The direct approach simply makes the screen jump. But thanks for taking time to show me this. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend changing the HTML to the following:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">auck</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then just use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
$(function(){
    $("#sidebar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
        }, 1000);     
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/VPzxG/1465/